# Redis list duplication

Tags: ruby, redis

I have a capped list using redis but I have a problem. This list is populated with last users to visit a page.

These data are stored like:

```
key: house:1
```

value:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John"
}
```

The problem is: if user changed his name another entry is made on the list.
How can I solve this ?

Comment: you can get the data by given key and overwrite the value... something like `data = JSON.parse(redis.get('house:1)); data[:name] = 'foo'; redis.set('house:1', data)`

Comment: @mr_sudaca Yes, but be careful. JSON keys are strings, so `data['name']` is the more accurate way to apply that.

Comment: @tadman ah ok.. yeah, sometimes I forget if those are strings or symbols...